# Looking for RegEx to grab element that doesn't match attribute

Tags: c#, regex

I have an XML-like file that has lines that look like this:

```
<siteMapNode title="Our Clients" url="~/OurClients">
    <siteMapNode title="Website Portfolio" url="~/OurClients/Portfolio" />
    <siteMapNode title="Testimonials" url="~/OurClients/Testimonials" />
</siteMapNode>

<siteMapNode title="Contact" url="~/Contact" />
<siteMapNode title="" url="~/Pharmacy" />
<siteMapNode url="~/ClinicWebsiteDevelopment" />
<siteMapNode url="~/HospitalWebsiteDevelopment" />
```

Notice how most of lines have a title attribute? What I want to do is use RegEx to capture all elements that do NOT have a `title` attribute AND I want to capture all lines that have  an empty title attribute `title=""`. So after running my example here through the RegEx, it should return me my last three lines, since the last two lines have no title attribute and the line before that has an empty title attribute.

Can someone please help me out on created this RegEx? This is for .NET by the way.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want other people to feel pain if you enjoy it yourself? It is so much easier to read XML as XML and use corresponding mechanisms to get values... Consider adding compelling reason why you must use RegEx to parse something that is generically not parable by RegEx...

Comment: Use xpath, easy with .NET and more appropriate way of doing this.

Comment: Guys, I can't use any kind of XML because my source file is not in XML format. Its in a proprietary format. The example I gave you looks like XML, but its not standard XML that conforms to any kind of known standard. Using xpath throws an error.

Comment: Linq to XML will handle a fragment like this one just fine. All you'd have to do is traverse the document nodes and find the ones where the attribute is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this easily with Linq2XML if you're willing to add a bogus root element (assuming there is none):

```
string foo = @"<bogus><siteMapNode title='Our Clients' url='~/OurClients'>
                <siteMapNode title='Website Portfolio' url='~/OurClients/Portfolio' />
                <siteMapNode title='Testimonials' url='~/OurClients/Testimonials' />
                </siteMapNode>

            <siteMapNode title='Contact' url='~/Contact' />
            <siteMapNode title='' url='~/Pharmacy' />
            <siteMapNode url='~/ClinicWebsiteDevelopment' />
            <siteMapNode url='~/HospitalWebsiteDevelopment' /></bogus>";


XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(foo);

var elements = doc.Root.Elements("siteMapNode");
foreach (var elem in elements) {
    if (elem.Attribute("title") == null)
        Console.WriteLine("This one doesn't have the attribute!");
}
```

No need to use regular expressions. Regexen should *never* be used to parse markup. Even if your document is in a format that is not valid XML, it can still be parsed so long as you can extract fragments from it. Honestly I think this is a better/faster/simpler way to go about it.

Comment: Of all my responses, this is probably the best way to do this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

use linq to xml 
here an explanation
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24376/LINQ-to-XML

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can't write a regexp to match a line that *doesn't* have a string. Instead, write a regexp that matches what you want, loop over the lines, test them against the regexp, and if the test fails add the line to the result list. So it would be something like (this is pseudo-code, not real C#):

```
while (line = nextline())
  if (re_match(/title=""/, line) || !re_match(/title=/, line)) 
    add_line_to_results(line);
```

Comment: Yes you can it's what the negative look behinds and lookaheads are for

Comment: Good point, if your regexp library implements full PCRE. I think `/^(?!.*\btitle=.*$)|\btitle=""/` does it.

Comment: Yes .Net supports them, but you should shorten to just avoid `title="[^"]`

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
(?m-s)^\s*<siteMapNode (?!.*title="[^"]).*?>
```

`(?m-s)` = process line by line

`^\s*`   = match optional whitespace at start

`<siteMapNode` = match tag

`(?!.*title="[^"])` = Non capturing test condition cannot match title="  (the [^"] caters for the empty title case

`.*?>` = match to end of tag

Comment: To make the answer a bit more generic, (?m-s)^\s*<[\w](?!.*title="[^"]).*?>  should work for any element name while still avoiding closing tags.